# socket.io not working properly for broadcast application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am using this code for simple broadcasting things.

server side

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
console.log( "New client !" );

client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

    client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    client.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
});
});

server.listen( 16558 );
```

and for the client side I am using this code to send and receive messages from other users who are online
Clientside

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:16558' );

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();

socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

// Ajax call for saving datas
$.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/insertNewMessage.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
    success: function(data) {

    }
});

return false;
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

$( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

socket.emit is not working on client side.

when new client is added "New client" is displayed on console but when any user send message it is not displayed on console

I am not getting error but the messages are not broadcasted.
Can any one help me regarding this.
is there any other event or methods I can used as its look like emit is not working properly

Comment: Try using this - 
`socket.join("roomName");`
Above line should be below `console.log("New Client");`

Comment: Also, while broadcasting use this `io.sockets.in('roomName').emit('event_name', data)`
This is from `https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms`

Comment: Could be a client side issue because socket seems to be working. Maybe the jquery part is not working as expected. Check the names and function calls. Is it actually calling sending message to server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );
```

try this

```
socket.emit( 'message', nameVal, msg  );
```